# Does a word checking algorithm exist?

Tags: algorithm

I've been thinking of if this was created already but image a function that can validate a string and determine if it's a word or not. eg

```
 print(validateWord("Hello")) --> true
 print(validateWord("Haloe")) --> true (may not be a real word but follows the standards of placements of vowels and such)
 print(validateWord("sewxdw")) --> false
```

I'm not asking for code, I would just like knowledge of if this exists already and a wiki post to this algorithm would be nice if it did.

Comment: Depends upon the language and definition of "word". So in general: no. Though such an algorithm or at least an approximation may exist for certain languages. In short: in it's current state this question is way too broad and there quite likely exist duplicates for specific languages already.

Comment: By asking about an "algorithm", are you looking for something that solves the problem without simply looking up your input in a dictionary containing valid words?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz: the difficulty is finding a dictionary that contains *all* valid words for a language.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Here's a list that claims 497K words. https://github.com/dwyl/english-words  I stopped my search with this one. I'm sure there are others. Are any of them all valid English words? No, but you're not going to get that without paying one of the major dictionary companies. Also, you can use a stemming algorithm on the input to reduce it to the most basic form of the word, so you don't really need a list of all valid words - just the stems.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a hidden Markov model, trained on the words in a corpus of English (or whatever language you are interested in). You can then score putative words for whether the model likes them or not. It will only disallow actually disallowed combinations like "jx" but it should give a low score to unlikely candidates.

You might have better luck trying to break up the text into phoneme symbols (th, ae  qu, ph etc) first rather than writing a model that uses raw letters.